# Merging arrays even if they don't exist with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I currently have 3 arrays, $A, $B and $C that I need to merge into a singe array called $allArrays.

I know I can do this with array_merge

```
$allArrays = array_merge($A,$B, $C);
```

But sometimes not all 3 arrays will exist.  Depending on if a user of this site I am working on activates an option that would create an array, I sometimes might only end up with 1 of the three, 2 of the three or maybe all 3.

So if user 1 actives an option that creates array $A and $B, while user 2 actives an option that creates array $A and $C, regardless one, both, or all three need to be merged to $allArrays.

How can I do this?  Currently, if I don't active all three arrays, allArrays comes back blank and empty, 0.

I feel like I could easily achieve this with multiple if statements to see if all arrays exists but I feel like that's a bit excessive.  I am new with PHP so looking into what to search for has been difficult.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not create all 3 arrays empty before and if the options fit, put data in some

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but didn't know if it'd be the right, or easiest way.  But for the sake of getting things done, I think this would work.

Comment: or you can use isset()

Comment: Yes, as I see it you can either create all three arrays empty or check if they are set - but I don't think one solution is better than another

Comment: it'll end up being code heavy since I plan to add a few dozen options, but for now, it'll work.  Test site needs to be simple enough so I cna pass it along to developers. ha.

Comment: Check out Babas answer, I think it is the best one. If you typecast and the variable is not set, it works just fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try simple typecast before you merge ..

```
$A = $B = $C = null;
$allArrays = array_merge((array) $A, (array) $B, (array) $C);
```

Comment: Why setting `null` and then typecast and not simply `array()`?

Comment: `But sometimes not all 3 arrays will exist` just given an example that if they don't exist ...

Comment: I believe he's suggesting: `$A = $B = $C = array();` and then no typecast.

Comment: @MichaelRushton that might still fail in some cases http://codepad.viper-7.com/GJ3Shu